# Non-block poll from two pipes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, pipe, fifo

Here is what I want to do..

```
mkfifo infrequentlog frequentlog
sort -m infrequentlog frequentlog > mylog
funcA > infrequentlog 
funcB > frequentlog
```

So that when monitor tail, I can see the dates are sorted from both logs.

```
tail -f mylog
```

The problem is that this thing doesn't print until funcA produce something. What I want is that even funcA doesn't produce something for a while, I still get something about funcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a third pipe and continuously copy the first two pipes into it. Then read the third:

```
while cp infrequentlog mainlog; do :; done &
while cp frequentlog mainlog; do :; done &

sort mainlog > mylog
```

You will need to repeat the sort as well to get all of the messages.